# Rails, Model Relationship Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have the following which works great:

```
@request_thread = current_user.request_threads.new(params[:request_thread])
```

And I have this which works great:

```
@requestable = find_requestable
@request_thread = @requestable.request_threads.new(params[:request_thread])
```

But if I try the 2nd line with:

```
@request_thread = @requestable.current_user.request_threads.new(params[:request_thread])
```

With the current_user I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `current_user' for #<Photo:0x10f95c828>):
app/controllers/request_threads_controller.rb:52:in `create'
app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
```

What did I mess up on here?

Thanks

**UPDATE - with find_requestable**

```
  # http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association
  def find_requestable  
    params.each do |name, value|  
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)  
      end  
    end  
    nil  
  end
```

Comment: maybe something like this... @requestable.find_by_user(current_user).request_threads.new(params[:request_thread])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly whats wrong: `current_user` doesn't exist for the `@requestable` object, whatever that is.

`current_user` is most likely a function inherited from `ApplicationController`, or at least that's usually where it lives. It usually returns a User object according to the current session. But that isn't a built-in part of Rails, so we need more information if you want me to go into greater detail.

`@requestable` looks like a polymorphic model instance so it wouldn't be aware of the current session.

---

There's a bit of Rails magic happening here that I think is confusing you.

Both `@requestable.request_threads` and `current_user.request_threads` are helper functions that have been generated by Rails on those objects to save you time by filtering results and filling in values automatically.

I think, by the code you have shown us so far, that you are trying to associate `current_user` with the new `request_thread` you are creating. In that case, you can simple merge that into the attributes manually. Since I don't know what your models look like I can only guess at the field names:

```
@request_thread = @requestable.request_threads.new( params[:request_thread].merge(:user => current_user) )
```

Like I said, the chainable functions are merely for convenience. For instance, you could write it this way instead:

```
@request_thread = request_thread.new(params[:request_thread])
@request_thread.requestable = find_requestable
@request_thread.user = current_user
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. You're right, requestable is a polymorphic model with references.

Comment: Just added what find_requestable. Is there other info that would be helpful? thxs

Comment: re current_user, correct it is a user object, powered by devise.